# Top Border Equal To Wrapping Text Width

Tags: css

In the bellow code the blue block has a green overline that should be the same width as the text and not overflow. Similar to the pink blocks notice how the green border is the same width as the text.

I've tried using `display: inline` as well with no luck. Is there maybe some hack to get this to work properly?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xq10dnb9/

CSS:

```
html {
  font-size: 50px;
}
.blue {
  background-color: #a9f4f4;
}
.blocks {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 700px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.block {
  padding: 5px;
  white-space: normal;
}
.block span {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
/*   display:inline; */
}
.block span:before {
  content: '';
  height: 4px;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="blocks">
  <div class="block"><span>1 Test</span></div>
  <div class="block blue"><span>Test123 Test</span></div>
  <div class="block"><span>Testi</span></div>
  <div class="block"><span>T asd</span></div>
  <div class="block"><span>Testing 5</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You cannot do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `width: min-content` in:

```
.block span{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: min-content;
 }
```

Comment: Never seen min-content before. Thanks for teaching me something new today. =)

Answer (score 0):

```
.block {
  padding: 5px;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

When you are using `padding,`you might want to specify where you want to add padding to like `padding-top, padding-bottom, padding-right or padding-left`. If you just type `padding` it will just add space to all side.

So, change it to

```
.block {
  padding-top: 5px;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

Is should solve the issue.
And you add this to your code

```
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: This did not fix the issue. The green bar is still the same as before. Thanks for trying.